# Change Composed Look on muliple Site Collections

Tags: powershell, site-collection, composed-looks

I need to create 100+ site collections in SP2013. I have a PowerShell script and XML file to achieve this (and is working).

However, marketing want to brand and change the look of the Team Sites - I'm just going to use the 'Grey' composed look for now.

(Ultimately I would like to include theme/logo/look change in initial site collection script) But for now I'm hoping someone can shed light on the error described.

The script I have to do this (i.e. it changes composed look retrospectively)

> doesn't work - Exception Calling "ApplyTheme" with "4" arguments(s):
>   "The Web application at http://_catalogs/theme/15/Palette032.spcolor
>   could not be found. Verify...."

The http address is clearly incorrect but I am using ServerRelativeURL? The spcolor `http://xxx.xxxxx.org.uk/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette032.spcolo`r file exists

The script is:

```
$themeName = "Grey"

$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://xxx.xxxxx.org.uk" 

foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs) 

{
  $SPWeb.allowunsafeupdates = $true

  $fontSchemeUrl = $SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + ""

  $themeurl = $SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette032.spcolor"

  $imageUrl = $SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + ""

  **$SPWeb.ApplyTheme($themeUrl, $fontSchemeUrl, $imageUrl, $false);**

  Write-Host "Set" $themeName "at :" $SPWeb.Title "(" $SPWeb.Url ")" 

  $SPWeb.Update()

  $SPWeb.allowunsafeupdates = $false

  $SPWeb.Dispose()

}  
$SPSite.Dispose()
```

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ApplyTheme "prefers" absolute urls, so you need to replace *ServerRelativeUrl* with *Url*. Code will look like this:

```
$themeName = "Grey"
$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://xxx.xxxxx.org.uk" 
foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs) 
{
  $fontSchemeUrl = $SPWeb.Url+ ""
  $themeurl = $SPWeb.Url + "/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette032.spcolor"
  $imageUrl = $SPWeb.Url + ""
  $SPWeb.ApplyTheme($themeUrl, $fontSchemeUrl, $imageUrl, $false);
  Write-Host "Set" $themeName "at :" $SPWeb.Title "(" $SPWeb.Url ")" 
  $SPWeb.Dispose()
}  
$SPSite.Dispose()
```

PS. You don't need *allowunsafeupdates* in PowerShell :)